# Junit 5 : Testing if condition involving private property in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to write a Junit test for the following controller:

```java
@Value("${custom.properties.list}")
private List<String> stringList;

final DataService dataService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createValue(
            @Valid @RequestBody final ObjectDto dto,
            @RequestHeader(value = "headerField") final String headerValue) {

        if (this.stringList.stream().noneMatch(headerValue::startsWith)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("error 403");
        }

        Long idResult = this.dataService.create(dto, headerValue);

        if (Objects.equals(idResult, -1L)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.204).body("error 204");
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(idResult, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

let's say that `stringList` contains values `"ABC", "EFG", "HIJ"`.
I'm testing that `headerValue` starts with one of the values from the list to either return a code 201 or 204.

My Junit test is the following:

```java
    @Test
    void testCreateValue_1() throws Exception {

        String requestBody = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/test/resources/post/postRequest_1.json")));

        MyObjectData data = mapper.readValue(requestBody, MyObjectData.class);

        Mockito.when(dataService.create(data, "ABC")).thenReturn(1L);

        mvc.perform(post("/")
                        .header("Nom-Application", "ABC")
                        .content(requestBody)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated());
    }
```

I am not sure why as I'm quite new to Junit testing, but running my test fails returns a code 403.
I've tried to create the list in my controller test class like I did it my controller class, but it doesn't work.

What should I do for my test to pass and return a code 201 ?

EDIT: Or maybe is has to do with getting my stringList from a properties file ?

EDIT 2 : I realised that the only value in `stringList` when I launch my test is `"${custom.properties.list}"`, so the answer to my previous edit is "yes". Is there any way I can update that value in my test class ?

Comment: Depending on the profile you are using for tests different application.yml might be loaded that does contain a different list. Did you set a debug breakpoint in the line of your first if condition to check what the stringList actually contains?

Comment: I do have 2 different file properties, but I only load one of the two, which is the only one to contain ```custom.properties.list```. I did, and the list contains ```"${custom.properties.list}"``` as the only value in my list, which matches none of the values I set in my properties file

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was creating a test.properties in my test file (making sure the path is the same that the one in the /src/main directory), and marking my test class with the following annotation `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")`.
This annotation means that the `test.properties` will override properties file that are in the main directory. Problem solved, all my test are successful.